# AWS EC2: How to prevent infinite loop for instance status check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have the following python boto3 code with a potentially infinite `while-loop`. Generally, after a few minutes the `while-loop` succeeds. However, if something fails on the AWS side the program could hang for an indefinite period.

I am sure that this is not the most appropriate way to do this.

```
# credentials stored in ../.aws/credentials
# region stored in ../.aws/config

# builtins
from time import sleep
# plugins
import boto3

# Assign server instance IDs.
cye_production_web_server_2 = 'i-FAKE-ID'

# Setup EC2 client
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

# Start the second web server.
start_response = ec2.start_instances(
    InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    DryRun=False
)

print(
    'instance id:',
    start_response['StartingInstances'][0]['InstanceId'],
    'is',
    start_response['StartingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name']
)

# Wait until status is 'ok'
status = None
while status != 'ok':
    status_response = ec2.describe_instance_status(
        DryRun=False,
        InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    )
    status = status_response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']['Status']
    sleep(5)    # 5 second throttle

print(status_response)
print('status is', status.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a counter in the loop and fail after so many attempts

```
status = None
counter = 5
while (status != 'ok' and counter > 0):
    status_response = ec2.describe_instance_status(
        DryRun=False,
        InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    )
    status = status_response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']['Status']
    sleep(5)    # 5 second throttle
    counter=counter-1

print(status_response)
print('status is', status.capitalize())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it in a `for` loop instead with a fixed number of tries.

For example:

```
MAX_RETRIES = 5

# Try until status is 'ok'
for x in range(MAX_RETRIES):
    status_response = ec2.describe_instance_status(
        DryRun=False,
        InstanceIds=[cye_production_web_server_2, ],
    )
    status = status_response['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']['Status']
    if status != 'ok':
        sleep(5)    # 5 second throttle
    else:
        break
```

Comment: ok so 5 retries translations to (5sec * 5retries = 25seconds), and I could increase or decrease this value.  Is there a reason for not using a while-loop in this case. The for-loop (in this case seems more verbose).

Comment: It is a little more verbose, it's true. You could use a while loop as the other responder suggested and that would work too. The reason not to use the while loop is to prevent getting stuck in an infinite loop as you describe

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout might be a better idea

```
import time 

systemstatus = False
timeout = time.time() + 60*minute

while systemstatus is not True:
    status = ec2.describe_instance_status( \
                 DryRun = False,
                 InstanceIds = [instance_id]
             )

    if status['InstanceStatuses'][0]['SystemStatus']['Status'] == 'ok':
        systemstatus = True

    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(10)
```